# Testing APIs workflow -session createRQ-FAILED

Tags: sabre

I am testing SABRE APIs in SOAUI. After following their procedure in git and imported the APIs workflows I tested the Book Air Segment workflow but I get the following error message:

> ```
>             SessionCreateRQ - FAILED - 1041 
>           - [Not SOAP Fault] Response is a SOAP Fault 
>           - [Contains Approved] Missing token [(?s).*status="Approved".*] in 
>              Response
> ```

I am not having a PCC so, I am using the default IPCC, endpoints are the normal test endpoints cert.....Domain: DEFAULT 
Should the ConversationID be set?

Below is the response from SOAP:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap- 
   env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
  <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" 
    xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
     <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">123123</eb:PartyId>
     </eb:From>
     <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">999999</eb:PartyId>
     </eb:To>
     <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
     <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-IPCC</eb:ConversationId>
     <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
     <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
     <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>1151090667624110610</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2018-04-29T18:32:42</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
     </eb:MessageData>
  </eb:MessageHeader>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
    </soap-env:Header>
     <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthenticationFailed</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Authentication failed</faultstring>
     <detail>
           <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.
   base.security.AuthenticationException: 
              errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
                </detail>
               </soap-env:Fault>
            </soap-env:Body>
             </soap-env:Envelope>



TestCase [Workflow: Book Air Segment] failed without assertions

at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.throwFailureException(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:519)
at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:435)
at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:202)
at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:137)
at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.runFromCommandLine(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:112)
at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.main(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:122)
20:32:44,502 WARN  [Tools] Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\b2bdd89e-146b-4b64-a000-f916daa3c7ad
20:32:44,515 WARN  [Tools] Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\8546b585-7998-4c11-a31f-97cfe83a13ff
```

Answer (score 0):

USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED means that the credentials used are not correct or inactive. You can see that **[HERE](https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/about_sabre_apis/sabre_apis_errors)**.

In either case, you should contact the API Support.